# index.php with a trailing slash is redirected to an absolute path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I type in the browser address bar

`www.mysite.com/index.php/`

and I get redirected to

`www.mysite.com/home/user/domains/mysite.com/public_html/index.php`

What does it mean?

Should I use *.htaccess* to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

I noticed that if I load `mysite.com/index.php/` without `www.` prefix, I get the URL not found message as expected and no redirection is made.

Comment: Well, some kind of rule get's executed. I would recommend puting `RewriteBase /` before the rules.

Comment: I do not have a *.htaccess* file in the root. If I add it with `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteBase /` it does not solve the issue.

Comment: It might be in the main config file (httpd.conf or something similar). Assuming you are 100% sure it is not caused by code in index.php itself, it's the only thing I can think of. If you don't have access to that file, contact your hoster.

Comment: I removed *index.php* from the root. The same behaviour.

Comment: I think your hoster made a rogue rewriterule. Contacting them is hopefully the easiest and fastest solution. I don't think you should try to fix this with .htaccess if you are not causing it yourself.

Comment: Maybe your .htaccess is hidden. Try to show hidden files and .htaccess may be there